# Get a default page for nuxt child

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router

## Context

I have a structure `pages` folder like this :

```
pages/
--| home.vue
--| index.vue
--| countries
----| countriesChildren
```

My index vue looks like this :

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <ToolbarMenu />
    <nuxt-child class='page-container'/>
  </div>
</template>
```

## Issue

The problem is that when Users go to `my-site.com/`, they go to index.vue but there isn't a default page to display.

 I would like to give them the home page which is right now located at `/home`

I can redirect users from `/` to `/home` but I am not sure it's the cleaner way :/ 
The best configuration would be: `/` is the home page without the `/home` path.

The structure would be :

`/` -> home page

`/countries` -> countries list

`/countries/country` -> country

and so on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found my issue ! This is my new structure:

```
pages/
--| index.vue (stay the same)
--| index/
----| index.vue (before was home.vue)
----| countries/
-------/ countriesChildren
```

The first index.vue got a `nuxt-child` which directly goes to the default page located to `index/index.vue`

To summarize:

- When the path is `my-site.com/`, `nuxt-child` is filled with
  index/index.vue (my home component)
- When the path is `my-site.com/countries/...`, `nuxt-child` is filled with countries folder

Comment: I'm using the same approach but when `keep-alive` is enabled, it will cause the index page to cache and show other sub-pages and doesn't show the index.vue content